# I'm trying to connect customer to User but getting this error: AttributeError at /user/' User' object has no attribute 'Customer

Tags: django

I'm trying to get the user data from Customer model. For this I also connect the Customer to User which I import from django.contrib.auth.models. But getting this error:
AttributeError at /user/
'User' object has no attribute 'Customer'

at views page:

```
    @login_required(login_url='login')
def user_page(request):
    orders=request.user.Customer.order_set.all()
    context={'orders':orders}
    return render(request, 'blog/user_page.html', context)
```

at models page

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model):
    User=models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email=models.EmailField()
    phone=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Kindly help If anyone know about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change it as follows

```
orders=Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

change the user to lower case in model fields

```
user=models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```